# YARN vCores used : Spark on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am submitting spark application on YARN with following configs

```
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "14g")
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
conf.set("spark.driver.cores", "5")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
```

But, On YARN Resource manager UI it's showing `vCores used = 5`, I am expecting vCores used to be **17 ((4x3)+5=17)** i.e 12 for executor and 5 for driver.
but it's always showing equal to **executors+driver=5**.

Please help me understand this!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the spark configuration [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties) you'll see the following:

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related to deploy, like “spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”, this kind of properties may not be affected when setting programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit command line options; another is mainly related to Spark runtime control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be set in either way.

Most of those settings you'll want to set from your `spark-submit` command line, as opposed to in the code. This is typically a better practice anyway, so that you can launch the job with different parameters, without having to re-compile it.

You'd want something like:

```
spark-submit --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 14g --driver-memory 1g --driver-cores 5 --class <main_class> <your_jar>
```

Comment: but the props which I have in code are getting reflected in the "spark env tab" on Web UI except vCores on YARN resource manager UI